# How to disable curved line ending in Windows API?

Tags: delphi, winapi, gdi

When I draw to a `TCanvas` using `LineTo()`, the lines end with a half circle bulge on them, not by a cut.

How can I disable this ending using the Windows API or Delphi's graphic system?

Comment: This (German) discussion has some sample code https://www.delphipraxis.net/92808-tcanvas-pen-und-die-abgerundeten-ecken.html

Comment: I tend to use GDI+ for these types of features. Much more difficult to use, but very flexible.